# How can I use this regex string in powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I've got a fairly simple PowerShell script that I can't get to work because of the RegEx in it. The RegEx which works just fine in Notepad++ is

Find: `^(?!7725_1|\"Dealer).*\r\n`

Replace:

This deletes all lines that don't begin with either "7725_1" or ""Dealer".

I've tried many different versions of the following Powershell script, including escaping all the regex characters with "`" and using the [Regex]::Replace function. All I've been able to deduce so far is that I'm doing something wrong -I just can't figure out what it is.

```
    (GC C:\Users\Bdraper\Desktop\Redrop1.csv) -Replace "^(?!7725_1|\"Dealer).*$\r\n",""|out-file -encoding ASCII C:\Users\Bdraper\Desktop\Redrop2.csv
```

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: `? { $_.StartsWith('7725_1') -or $_.StartsWith('"Dealer') }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that are probably tripping this up.

First thing to know is that you are using `gc` (`Get-Content`) which returns an array of lines. That means the `-replace` operator is operating on an array and will return an array with the replacements.

Because `Get-Content` returns lines, any CR of LF characters will not be present, so your regex will likely never match. It also means you'll get empty lines for the ones that do, probably not what you want.

A much easier thing to do with this knowledge then, is to use the `-match` operator, which will simplify your regex and the whole process:

```
(GC C:\Users\Bdraper\Desktop\Redrop1.csv) -match '^(7725_1|"Dealer)'| 
    out-file -encoding ASCII C:\Users\Bdraper\Desktop\Redrop2.csv
```

So basically, "give me all the lines that start with either of these strings" and then you just write those out to the file.

Comment: This worked beautifully and is so much simpler than what I was trying to do. Thank you very much for your help!!

This is what I get when I try to combine a cursory knowledge of regex with a cursory knowledge of powershell.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex won't match because you are not using quantifiers that allow you to cross multiple lines with your regex. Also your string is actually an array with `-replace` is willing to work with but not the way you would expect. Your quotes and newlines are incorrect as well since escaping in PowerShell uses backticks. Moving on though

> This deletes all lines that don't begin with either "7725_1" or ""Dealer".

Why not just filter those out with `-match` instead

```
(GC C:\Users\Bdraper\Desktop\Redrop1.csv) -match "^(7725_1|`"Dealer)" | 
    Set-Content C:\Users\Bdraper\Desktop\Redrop2.csv
```

So this will only allow items that start with 7725_1 or "Dealer to go into the output file. `Set-Content` is usually faster than `Out-File` and defaults to ASCII encoding as well.